# What would be the best approach to handle incase of exceptions while running Batch jobs?

Tags: cron, spring-batch, aws-glue, job-scheduling, aws-batch

I have written a Batch job in Java. My batch job which basically runs daily once and its logic is to make Rest call to some other api only. Incase of a success scenario, no issues, but incase of failure, which means the other api either throw some exception or could be any issue, then whats the approach in this negative scenario. Do we need to store those ids which got error responses and retry making requests for those ids in the very next scheduled job?

**What would be the best approach to handle incase of exceptions while running Batch jobs?**

Comment: anyone? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options:

- use the built-in retry mechanism in Spring Batch: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#retryLogic
- use a more cloud native approach with circuit-breakers or equivalent, see Michael's talk here: https://youtu.be/-Icd-s2JoAw?t=862